# TP Link Router - Inbound access with DDNS with Private IP?

Tags: networking, router, dns, ddns

I was going thru the knowledge base/FAQs on TP Link Routers about Dynamic DNS [here](https://www.tp-link.com/us/support/faq/1367/).

I am a bit confused about the 3rd point in the Notes written therein.

> Notes:
>
> 1. Make sure you have internet when you’re registering a TP-LINK domain name.
> 2. If you fail to register a TP-LINK domain name, it means your domain name has been registered by others. Please try to change
>      another hostname.
> 3. Your domain name will be bound to the external public IP address of your network. So don’t worry if the ISP assigns a private WAN IP
>      address (such as 192.168.1.x) to the router.
> 4. If you want to change the domain name, just click Unbind and Delete your current domain name. Then tap Register to bind a new one.

The question is why shouldn't I be worried if the ISP assigns Private IP to my router, when I want to establish an Inbound connection? In that case even if router has Private IP, for an inbound connection, who/what will ensure routing from the ISP's device that has routable Public IP to my router that now has a private IP?

Does the TP Link router establish some sort of outbound connection to the DDNS service? 
I am under the impression that seamless Remote Wake-On-LAN or remote access to your home network device (from the Internet) is possible when ISP assigns a Public IP to your Router (And of course required port forwarding is set up in Router config wherever needed). If your router has a private IP it gets complicated I suppose.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I made some researches on the web, and I found that almost every manual states that if the ISP assigns you a private WAN address (and if so, you are likely under a multi layer NAT), the DDNS service **doesn't work**. [TL-MR6400](https://images-eu.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/A1t5ozR3ijS.pdf), [TD-W9960](https://www.o2.cz/_pub/d3/b2/8d/616760_1456296__1910012403_TD_W9960_EU__UG.pdf), [Archer C1200](https://gzhls.at/blob/ldb/2/f/0/8/08a67829643f251d5bfe574dd218db868a8a.pdf) are all TP-Link models. Even the [Archer C8](https://static.tp-link.com/2018/201801/20180125/1910011900_Archer%20C8_UG_V3.pdf) manual states that the service doesn't work in such condition, which is contradictory because [here](https://www.tp-link.com/it/support/faq/1367/) it is said quite the opposite. I cannot tell, I know that there are some workarounds and somebody managed to have a DDNS working in some strange cases ([this](https://community.ui.com/questions/Dynamic-DNS-DDNS-from-behind-a-NAT-ADSL-router-No-IP-com-WORKING/6858ea39-5c1d-4687-a514-bb71f994358b) seems to work for some people, but it's a very specific solution), but in such an uncertain condition, I would definitely open a ticket asking for clarifications.